# What is the difference between "gradle bootRun" and "gradle run" to run a springboot application?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

To run a Spring Boot application, there are two gradle tasks:

1. `gradle bootRun`
2. `gradle run`

Both tasks can be used to run the Spring Boot application, what are the main differences between these tasks?

Answer (score 50):

1. `gradle bootRun` - standard gradle'run' task with additional Spring Boot features. e.g. you can type: `bootRun {addResources = false}`[check github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/run/BootRun.java)
2. `gradle run` standard gradle 'run' task